# success_url for Django LoginView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

High level question: Can I use the `success_url` attribute to change to where a view inheriting from Django's `LoginView` will redirect?

I have a login view that looks something like the below (ignoring import statements):

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'myapp/mytemplate.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:my_success_view')
```

However, my login view still redirects to my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL from my settings.py. Is this the wrong way to change my redirect url in the view?

**Edit** Since part of the issue might be the template, I'm including the submit button portion of my template. here is how it looks after taking into account Mehdi's answer (behavior did not change).

```
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4" style="width: 100%">   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">
                Log In
            </button>
        </div>
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{% url 'myapp:mytemplatename' %}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template you should use a next input like this:

`<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{% url 'success_view' %}>`

You can custom its name with `redirect_field_name` attribute of your view. See class documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

Comment: And can this go anywhere within the form tags in the template?

Comment: Sure, there is an example in the link I posted if you want.

Comment: Cool, I added this to the template and it still doesn't seem to be working. I'm going to think about it for a bit, but if you know of any obvious reasons why including this in the template wouldn't change the behavior that would be really helpful

Comment: Cant think of anything obvious. Does the url tag render the expected value and is it received in your view ?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the url tag renders the expected value, but still the redirect is going to the url that I have set in LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in my settings.py. Does this next parameter approach override LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL?

Comment: From the doc:

Here’s what LoginView does:

    If called via GET, it displays a login form that POSTs to the same URL. More on this in a bit.
    If called via POST with user submitted credentials, it tries to log the user in. If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL specified in next. If next isn’t provided, it redirects to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL (which defaults to /accounts/profile/). If login isn’t successful, it redisplays the login form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171434/discussion-between-connor-roberts-and-mehdi-b).